# Замена ссылок в contenteditable div, кроме явно указаных

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

нужно обернуть в тег `а` все вхождения по регулярке, но не заменять в уже готовых тегах `а`
написал следующее

```
function replaceURLsInMessage(text){
    text = text.replace(/(?<![">])(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.(?!gif|png|jpg)[a-z]{2,6}\b)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)(?!["<])/g, '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>');
    return text;
}
```

во первых js ругается на регулярку

во вторых, регулярка не работает если внутри тега `а` написана ссылка посреди текста.

второе то ладно, в приоритете первый пункт

прилагаю пример текста

```
fadsgfads
<a href="vk.com" target="_blank">Смотрите в vk.com подробнее </a>
фывафывафыва
вафывафыва
афвыафыва м vk.com
фывафыва
```

вызов осуществляется следующим образом по клике на кнопку

```
$this.html(replaceURLsInMessage($this.html()))
```

в результате ожидаю увидеть следующее

```
fadsgfads
<a href="vk.com" target="_blank">Смотрите в vk.com подробнее </a>
фывафывафыва
вафывафыва
афвыафыва м <a href="vk.com" target="_blank">vk.com</a>
фывафыва
```

то есть первая ссылка осталось не тронутая, а вторая - та что была текстом, стала ссылкой, ссылка и в `href` и внутри самого тега `а`

Comment: это одна из причин, почему не стоит использовать регулярки при работе с Html :-)

Comment: как ты вызываешь эту функцию и добавь примеры текста, который может передаваться

Comment: вызываю по нажатию на сохранить, на подобии
$this.html(replaceURLsInMessage($this.html())) - как пример

Comment: код тоже в вопрос. А заменяешь по кнопке? или как?

Comment: да, все верно - по кнопке

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, _Замена ссылок в **contenteditable div**_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если хотите пользоваться регулярным выражением, можно воспользоваться захватывающими подмасками и анализировать внутри анонимного метода захваченные тексты, а потом и решать, что с ними делать.

```js
$("div").each(function() {
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/<a\s+[^<]*?>[^<]*<\/a>|((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.(?!gif|png|jpg)[a-z]{2,6}\b)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&\/=]*)/ig, function($0, $1) {
     return $1 ? '<a href="' + $1 + '">' + $1 + '</a>' : $0;
    }));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">fadsgfads
<a href="vk.com" target="_blank">Смотрите в vk.com подробнее </a>
фывафывафыва
вафывафыва
афвыафыва м vk.com
фывафыва</div>
```

Т.е. с помощью `<a\s+[^<]*?>[^<]*<\/a>` можно отловить уже готовые ссылки с тегами, а с помощью Вашего выражения (но уже в `(...)`) можно найти ссылки без тегов. Если подмаска №1 найдена (`$1 ?`), надо добавить теги. Если нет, просто вставляем обратно полное совпадение `$0`.

Comment: ОНО, огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Javascript не поддерживает [просмотра назад](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4) в регулярных выражениях. По этому `(?<![">])` ведет к

> во первых js ругается на регулярку

Comment: Может есть какие нибудь варианты, главное результат)) не поддерживает так не поддерживает, теперь стало ясно

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, ошибка в самом начале: что за неэкранированный вопросительный знак в самом начале, сразу после открывающейся скобки? Не припомню такого синтаксиса в Javascript. Если вы имели ввиду именно символ "?", а не оператор регулярки, то экранируйте  его:

```
text.replace(/(\?<![">])(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.(?!gif|png|jpg)[a-z]{2,6}\b)([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)(?!["<])/g, '<a href="$&" target="_blank">$&</a>');
```

Теперь регулярка не выплевывает ошибку. Насколько она рабочая - судить вам. Если дадите пример сложного текста и опишите желаемое - дополним регулярку.

Comment: пример дан, условие тоже, ввиду имелся конечно же не вопросительный знак, читайте пожалуйста внимательнее условие

Comment: @sivik_xes прочитал, раз 5 уже. "js ругается на регулярку" у вас в приоритете. Я указал на ошибку, на которую он ругается. Теперь, когда вы дополнили ответ, стало яснее. Интересная задача...

Comment: извините, а что из этого условия вам было не ясно?
нужно обернуть в тег а все вхождения по регулярке, но не заменять в уже готовых тегах а написал следующее

Comment: @sivik_xes четко не было ясно, что такое "вхождения по регулярке". ваше дополнение прояснило ситуацию.